# Java SQL Query Resultset always returns null can't find solution

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, resultset

I am trying to check if a user entered Username and password matches one in my data base however what ever I try the result set still comes up null. the sql varible is set to the username and the pass is set to the password however when ever i enter the correct details it shows up with no results

```
public boolean Login(){
    boolean valid = true;
        try {
            String stmt = "SELECT * From TBLUser where User = ? and Password = ? ;";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(stmt);
            pstmt.setString(1, sql); pstmt.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if(!rs.next()){
                valid = false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: "+e);
        }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: I do not see the values for `sql` and `pass` . Also, the `;` in the statement sql is not needed.

Comment: the sql and pass values are set in another class

Comment: Are you getting a stack trace? Have you tried to manually run the query with the same values? Are you 100% you the values for `sql` (???) and `pass` are set when the query is being executed? ... I guess what I really need to ask is how is this method accessing those values?

Comment: I tried manualy running the query in ms access and it works. Sql and pass are set from a txtfeild. I know that the feilds are set because I have printed them in a system out

Comment: how does the method in question gain access? Are these instance variables of the containing class? *** Do you have a stack trace? ***

Comment: There is no stack trace but the variables are pary of the database connection class.

Comment: @Arcticfrog Did you run this through a debugger or use println in the method. Perhaps you can share the values you are testing with?

Comment: @Arcticfrog Is there a reason you don't just pass these values in as I do in my answer.

Comment: I ran the program using eclipse debug aswell as used a println to check the values for sql and pass which are sql ="User1" and pass ="he11o" i tried passing these values like you did in your answer before but it did not work

Comment: Is there more that one table called TBLUser in the DB? Try qualifying the table in your query with the table owner.

Comment: @Arcticfrog Last suggestion -- try hardcoding the values in the method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is only one table in the DB that is called TBLUser and i tried hard coding in the valuses but it still does not work it seems to have a problem with the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the application is not the code but the database as User one of the column names is a reserved word so this change fixed the problem thanks to @Grayson for all the help

```
public boolean Login(){
boolean valid = true;
    try {
        String stmt = "SELECT * From TBLUser where UserName = ? and Password = ? ;";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(stmt);
        pstmt.setString(1, sql); pstmt.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if(!rs.next()){
            valid = false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: "+e);
    }
return valid;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Also, better practice:

```
public boolean Login(String asql, String apass){
    boolean valid = true;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            String stmt = "SELECT * From TBLUser where User = ? and Password = ? ";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(stmt);
            pstmt.setString(1, asql); 
            pstmt.setString(2, apass);

            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            valid = (!rs.next());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStaceTrace();
        } finally { // cleanup
          try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception ex) {}
          try { ps.close(); } catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unit cap with " " to save your column-Table like

Create Table "TBLUser"{
"User" char...
"Password"...
}

similarly, your select query will change String 
stmt = "SELECT * From \"TBLUser\" where \"User\" = ? and \"Password\" = ? "

This should work.